# db-migrate and db-migrate-pg How to control order of migrations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, dbmigrate

Is there a way to run only specific migration file using db-migrate, or to at least execute migrations in a specific order? Some workarounds would be to change the dates in migration file name, or to put all operations into one file, but I'm trying o find some more elegant way to do this.
In the [db-migrate documentation](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting%20Started/commands/) the is this command that is supposed to run one migration, but it actually runs all migrations before that as well:

```
db-migrate up 20150207135259-myFancyMigration
```